# python re find pattern and split into list

Tags: python, python-re, findall

I am looking to split the following string into the list as shown below:

```
string = 'M43.16: Spondylolisthesis, lumbar region, ' \
    'M51.27: Other intervertebral disc displacement, lumbosacral region, ' \
    'M54.17: Radiculopathy, lumbosacral region'
```

The "M43.16" like codes can be of varying length, all start with a capital letter, followed by digits with one decimal point and possibly end with a non-capital letter. Then it's followed by its description and what region of the body (separated by the second comma).

Desired list should split before the start of the next code and its description:

```
list = ['M43.16: Spondylolisthesis, lumbar region', 'M51.27: Other intervertebral disc displacement, lumbosacral region, 'M54.17: Radiculopathy, lumbosacral region']
```

What I've tried so far but fail to stop the match before the next code:

```
re.findall("[A-Z][A-Z0-9. ]*: [A-Za-z, ]* [A-Za-z, ]", string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r"[A-Z][A-Z0-9.]*: [A-Za-z ]+, [A-Za-z ]+", string)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked as well. This one even took the trailing comma off.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution. I used a matching pattern for the second part that is repeated and excludes `:`.

```
import re
re.findall("[A-Z][A-Z0-9. ]*:(?:\s*[^:]+,)+", string+',')
```

output:

```
['M43.16: Spondylolisthesis, lumbar region,',
 'M51.27: Other intervertebral disc displacement, lumbosacral region,',
 'M54.17: Radiculopathy, lumbosacral region,']
```

You can test the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/NnB7Ef/1)

Comment: Amazing! Worked like charm. I haven't used too much of regex so this is all new to me. I will learn from your work using https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

My attempt: `[\w.]*: [A-Za-z, ]*[^,\sA-Z\d]`.
No trailing commas or spaces.

```py
import re
s = "M43.16: Spondylolisthesis, lumbar region, M51.27: Other intervertebral disc displacement, lumbosacral region, M54.17: Radiculopathy, lumbosacral region"
re.findall(r"[\w.]*: [A-Za-z, ]*[^,\sA-Z\d]", s)

['M43.16: Spondylolisthesis, lumbar region',
 'M51.27: Other intervertebral disc displacement, lumbosacral region',
 'M54.17: Radiculopathy, lumbosacral region']
```

Comment: very nice ;) However this could have some side effects, imagine a string like `'M43.16: Spondylolisthesis, lumbar region B, M51.27: ...'`